# Programmaticaly install app from google play and get response

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

I am starting google play store from within my app to install a targeted app.

I know this can be achieved by using something like this:

```
try {
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ANFE) {
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}
```

**Question is** - Is there a way to know if the app was installed using this intent? Would something like `startActivityForResult()` work here? What kind of response can I expect?

Answer (score 0):

After you've launched your intent yo, your app can watch for the broadcast  `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` (see doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)).

What you should do is:

1. Add a service in your app to listen to `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED`
2. In this service, check if the name match to the one you want then trigger the event you want..
3. Launch your intent like in your question and wait the service to be triggered..

This may not be as simple as you want but I think this is the only way.